# Analysis of post transplantation lineage tags

Tags: genetics, molecular-biology

I'm having some trouble understanding some bits of a study, mostly about the Sleeping Beauty system and TARIS model, from this paper: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4408613/

I understand the concept, but not how it works technically. Can anyone explain it for me?

Answer (score 1):

I can't find a reference to a "TARIS model" in the paper you linked, but we can break down the molecular circuitry of this lineage tag tracking system step-by-step.

1. The authors use a type of [Tet expression system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetracycline-controlled_transcriptional_activation) in order to tightly control the expression of a [hyperactive](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC517896/) Sleeping Beauty (*HSB*) transposase.  In the absence of doxycycline, the reverse tetracycline-controlled transactivator *[M2-rtTA](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/11812277/)* does not bind the *TetO* operator. Jackson Labs has a very good [summary](https://www.jax.org/news-and-insights/2015/april/introduction-to-tet-expression-systems) of Tet-On (and Tet-Off) systems:

> ... rtTA is a fusion protein comprised of the TetR repressor and the VP16 transactivation domain; however, a four amino acid change in the tetR DNA binding moiety alters rtTA's binding characteristics such that it can only recognize the tetO sequences in the [tetracycline-responsive promoter element (TRE)] of the target transgene in the presence of the Dox effector. Thus, in the Tet-On system, transcription of the TRE-regulated target gene is stimulated by rtTA only in the presence of Dox.

2. In the presence of doxycycline, the transactivator drives expression of *HSB* from the constituent promoters of the *TetO* operator.  *HSB* contains DNA binding motifs that specifically recognize the direct repeats (white triangles) and a catalytic domain that excises the direct repeats and the DNA they flank, which contains a transcription stop signal (Tn-STOP).
3. Excision of the Tn-STOP signal allows for expression of *DsRed* driven by a strong synthetic promoter (CAGGS, first described [here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/1660837)).  The excised sequence is then inserted somewhere else in the genome.
4. Because successful Tn-STOP excision is concurrent with transcription of *DsRed*, red fluorescing cells can be selected and prepared for NGS.  *HSB* transposition is "random", so two different transposition events are unlikely to target the same insertion locus.  The specific insertion site can then be used as a molecular fingerprint to identify the progenitor stem cell after replication and differentiation.

[image: excerpt from Figure 1 of Sun et al. 2015]